# CSS positioning div within a div

Tags: html, css, styles, positioning

I have a div within a div that is giving me problems.

```
<div style="border:solid 20px #ccff33;border-radius:10px;height:300px;width:300px;margin:20px;display: inline-block">
    <img src="images/f35.jpg" style="margin-right:10px" />
    <div style="float:right;padding-left:10px; border-left:solid 1px #aaaaaa; font-size: 12px; display:inline-block">
        Some text here.
    </div>
</div>
```

This comes out with this:

[image: Example]

The div within the div is not displaying inline with the image. I basically need the text to be within the containing div and on the right of the image.

Just some points: I need to use divs (i.e. not tables) and the styles have to be inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `float` the image to the `left`. And make sure there is enough space to hold both of them in the `div` otherwise the right most element will break to the new line. And unless you meant to have a `20px` whitespace between the two you only need either `margin-right` or the `padding-left`.

```
<img src="images/f35.jpg" style="width:50%; float:left; margin-right:10px" />
<div style="width:50%; float:right; border-left:solid 1px #aaaaaa; font-size: 12px;">
```

Comment: +1 and check mark for being awesomely fast. Thanks bud, that works.

Answer (score 1):

`Float` the image `left` and give the `div` with the content a `width`, remember to `clear` the floats after...

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/xyYh5/

```
<div style="border:solid 20px #ccff33;border-radius:10px;height:300px;width:350px;margin:20px;display: inline-block">
    <img src="http://www.dothetest.co.uk/images/do-test.gif" style="margin-right:10px; float:left;" width="150"/>
    <div style="float:right;padding-left:10px; border-left:solid 1px #aaaaaa; font-size: 12px; display:inline-block;width:160px;" >
        Lorem ipsizzle break it down sure amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. Nullam funky fresh velizzle.
    </div>
</div>
```